# Tremoli in Lilypond look destroyed

Tags: lilypond

My tremoli between notes are looking so destroyed!:

[image]

I have added before each `repeat`:

```
\ftbt \override Beam.gap = #3
```

where `\ftbt` is:

```
ftbt = \once \override Beam.beam-thickness = #0.4
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

**UPDATE**
I'm adding the `Beam.gap` command to avoid collision of tremolo beams with accidentals, like this:

[image]

Comment: What do you want `Beam.gap = #3` to do?

Comment: @ElementsinSpace See the edited question for your answer please.

Comment: Can you not do neatly-edited screenshots rather than fuzzy out of square photos?

Comment: Thanks for the update, but it doesn't really explain the problem.  
Applying the beam gap override to a simple example with the semibreve/whole-note tremolo with an accidental, seems to work fine for me.  
Can you provide a Minimal Working Example? (just enough code that can be compiled and show the actual problem)

Comment: @Student Can you please give some details, such as: 1) Your exact problem, 2) Your Lilypond version, 3) Some code which produces the problem. Else it becomes very hard to help you. Note that there is not need to photograph your screen, you can do screenshots and Lilypond can even directly output png graphics.